# Solve the flask_restful error with Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have an error when I use docker, when I build my image, my Mongodb database launches but my python server does not launch and I get the following error:

```
2023-03-21 14:11:25 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-21 14:11:25   File "/app/ServeurWeb.py", line 5, in <module>
2023-03-21 14:11:25     from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
2023-03-21 14:11:25 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'
```

However flask_restful is installed on my computer with the command

```
pip install flask_restful
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install flask_restful` needs to be ran **inside of your Dockerfile**. Your host does not share packages with the image.

Ideally, you use a `requirements.txt` file, instead, however.

Answer (score 0):

create a `requirements.txt` file in the same directory as `Dockerfile`.
add `flask_restful` in the requirements.txt file.

Then add the below code in your dockerfile.

```
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note that if you install flask_restful in your host system, your docker container won't recognize that as docker container runs on a isolated environment.

Comment: I already do this and yes I installed flask_restful on my system so how can I do ?